# iOS: How to pass data to applicationDidFinishLaunching:?

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview

I have the following Code in my XMLAppDelegate.m file:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    self.products = [NSMutableArray array];
    XMLViewController *viewController = [[XMLViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.entries = self.products; // 2. Here my Array is EMPTY. Why?

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:productData]];
    self.XMLConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];

    NSAssert(self.XMLConnection != nil, @"Failure to create URL connection.");

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
}

- (void)handleLoadedXML:(NSArray *)loadedData {
    [self.products addObjectsFromArray:loadedData]; // 1. here I get my Data (works fine)

    XMLViewController *viewController = [[XMLViewController alloc] init];
    [viewController.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I marked the problem. Is there any possibility to pass the loaded data (loadedData) to applicationDidFinishLaunching:?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: In respone to number 2. Your array is empty because you have not filled it up with anything.

Comment: In response to number 1, where are you calling handleLoadedXML from?

Comment: Just a note, you shouldn't be doing any synchronous networking calls in your app delegate. This potentially slows down your launch with a greater risk of your app being quit by the OS because it's taking too long to launch. Either change it to an asynchronous request or do the request after your app has finished launching.

Comment: I thought it would be filled in number 1? handleLoadedXML gets called from didFinishParsing.. But this works fine (it's all filled in NSLog)

Comment: thank you @runmad for the advice :) I got the code from lazyTableImages and it's still in this form for testing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your `handleLoadedXML` get called? If you want to pass it to `applicationDidFinishLaunching` can you just have your `handleLoadedXML` return that array and you can then call that method in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

**Edit:**

Think of it this way:

You first have this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    self.products = [NSMutableArray array];
    XMLViewController *viewController = [[XMLViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.entries = self.products; // 2. Here my Array is EMPTY. Why?

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:productData]];
    self.XMLConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];

    NSAssert(self.XMLConnection != nil, @"Failure to create URL connection.");

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
}
```

Note that here you don't have `self.products` set up yet. It's only allocated.

After your application finished launching, then you have:

```
// say you have something like this
- (NSArray *)didFinishParsing {
    return someArray;
}
```

This method gets called somewhere, and then it calls the method below to set your `self.products`. Not until now is your `self.products` populated.

```
- (void)handleLoadedXML:(NSArray *)loadedData {
    [self.products addObjectsFromArray:loadedData]; // 1. here I get my Data (works fine)

    XMLViewController *viewController = [[XMLViewController alloc] init];
    [viewController.tableView reloadData];
}
```

So if you want `self.products` to be populated in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, you need to call the method that generates the array in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, say `didFinishParsing`, and you can do `self.products = [self didFinishParsing];`, and then it will be set.

Comment: what do you mean with 'return'?

Comment: i was saying that you can return the array you need. the thing is `applicationDidFinishLaunching` happens very early on. If you want `self.products` to be populated in it, you need to set it to something in there, not some other method.

Comment: thank you, @iBlue, but now I receive a warning: Void method ".." should not return a value.

Comment: that's because you put `-(void)someMethod` rather than `-(NSArray *)someMethod`. That thing in the () is your return type. It should match the actual return type.